# Make Gazebo (ODE) deterministic or reset random number generator?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am running a lot(~1000s) of quick simulations one at a time and doing a World::Reset() between each one. Is there some way to ensure that the random numbers generated by Gazebo are the same after each World::Reset()? Can I reset the RNG? If I just set the seed again, will that restart the RNG?

Right now, I have a small (~1 in 1000) chance of the RNG causing the result of my simulation to change - I'd like to fix the random numbers generated so that I can observe the behavior causing my simulation to fail. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4564/make-gazebo-(ode)-deterministic-or-reset-random-number-generator?/) by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 59 on 2013-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This may the tutorial you are looking for: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/rand

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on 2013-10-07**:
Thanks Nate! I've set the seed already. Unfortunately when I reset the world using World::Reset(), the RNG doesn't seem to reset and as a result I can run the same simulation over again and get different results. I would like to be able to reproduce my results and still automate the process of running multiple trials. How do you recommend that I do this?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-07**:
I've made an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/876/reset-random-number-generator) out of this. Please track updates there.

**Comment by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on 2013-10-07**:
Great, thanks!